# pythonでリストのfp.writeエラー

Tags: python

pythonでテキストから単語を抽出し、リストに代入しました

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys 
title = sys.argv[1:]

pare=[]
#vocab.txtから読み取り
for line in open(title[1]):
    line = line.split()
    i=0
    for word in line:

        if(i==0):
            pare.append(word)
            i+=1

fp = open('distance用words.txt','w')
```

その後、単語に割り当てられた数値に応じた単語を出力しようとした際に次のコードを書きました。

```
for line in open(title[0]):
    line = line.split()
    for score in line:
        fp.write(str(pare[score]))
        fp.write('\n')
fp.write('EXIT\n')
```

出力結果が

```
fp.write(str(pare[score]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

となり、エラーになります。どうしたら入力文字で出力できますか？

Comment: 入力テキストは1単語毎に単語とハッシュがスペース区切りで並んでいるだけのものです。

Comment: distance_vocab.txtは不要でした。すみません。あと、int(score)とすれば上手く行きました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自然言語処理とは直接関係がない内容なので、タグを外しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ご質問の回答になっているか自信ありませんが、エラーを取り除くのであれば以下だと思います。

```
--- a.py    2015-02-01 15:53:54.000000000 +0900
+++ b.py    2015-02-01 15:54:04.000000000 +0900
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 for line in open(title[0]):
     line = line.split()
     for score in line:
-        fp.write(str(pare[score]))
+        fp.write(str(pare[int(score)]))
         fp.write('\n')
 fp.write('EXIT\n')
```

Comment: +のところを-に直したのですが、同じエラーが出ました。

Comment: ごめんなさい、解り辛いですね。。fp.write(str(pare[score])) となっているところを、 fp.write(str(pare[int(score)])) とする(split で得られるものは文字列なので, pare の添字部を int(score) としてやる)と score が数値にできるのであれば、なんとかなりそうですが、どうでしょう？(削除を取り消して、復活させて、コメントを移動しました。。)

Comment: こちらこそ申し訳ありませんでした。こちらで勘違いをしてしまい、int str(pare[score])としていました。適切な解答通りに書けば正しく動作します。エラーの意味もわかりました。とても丁寧な解答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

```
fp.write(str(pare[score]))
```

のscore部を
    int(score)
とすれば上手く行きました。ありがとうございました。